# got "ClassNotFoundException" when reading binlog data from Kafka using Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, protocol-buffers, spark-streaming, binlog

I want to read the binlog data from kafka using Spark Streaming, the binlog data is collected using [canal](https://github.com/alibaba/canal)(which uses protobuf-2.4.1)，I have to use the protobuf-2.5.0 in the Spark Streaming environment. Now i got the following Exception

`16/07/11 15:13:01 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find proto buffer class
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm.readResolve(GeneratedMessageLite.java:775)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1807)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at com.data.binlog.BinlogEntryUtil.deserializeFromProtoBuf(BinlogEntryUtil.java:30)
    at main.com.data.scala.Utils$.binlogDecode(Utils.scala:30)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$4.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:37)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$4.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$5$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:42)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$5$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:59)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$.logInfo(IntegrateKafka.scala:16)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:42)
    at main.com.data.scala.IntegrateKafka$$anonfun$main$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(IntegrateKafka.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1850)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alibaba.otter.canal.protocol.CanalEntry$Entry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm.readResolve(GeneratedMessageLite.java:768)
    ... 29 more`

the code com.data.binlog.BinlogEntryUtil.deserializeFromProtoBuf is here

```
public static Entry deserializeFromProtoBuf(byte[] input) {
    Entry entry = null;

    try {
       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new   ByteArrayInputStream(input));

       entry = (Entry)ois.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       logger.error("Exception:" + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       logger.error("IOException " + e);
    }

    return entry;
}
```

But I find CanalEntry$Entry.class in my jar

> -rw----     2.0 fat    14431 bl defN 16-Jul-11 15:11 com/alibaba/otter/canal/protocol/CanalEntry$Entry.class

I have tried to generate the `CanalEntry.java` and `CanalPacket.java` using `protoc-2.5.0`, but gotten the same exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alibaba.otter.canal.protocol.CanalEntry$Entry`

Can anybody give me some suggestions to read the binlog data (serialized by `protobuf-2.4.1`) using `protobuf-2.5.0`?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some more tries, I find this is not protobuf's problem.
I get this problem, because the binlog datas aren't the pure protobuf bytes, they are serialized bytes of some other class which include the protobuf bytes.